# Cannot type any text in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have this DOM:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<div class="CodeMirror-scroll" tabindex="-1" draggable="true">
   <div class="CodeMirror-sizer" style="margin-left: 53px; margin-bottom: -16px; border-right-width: 14px; min-height: 26px; min-width: 7px; padding-right: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px;">
      <div style="position: relative; top: 0px;">
         <div class="CodeMirror-lines" role="presentation">
            <div style="position: relative; outline: medium none currentcolor;" role="presentation">
               <div class="CodeMirror-measure" />
               <div class="CodeMirror-measure" />
               <div style="position: relative; z-index: 1;" />
               <div class="CodeMirror-cursors" style="" />
               <div class="CodeMirror-code" role="presentation" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="false" tabindex="0" contenteditable="true">
                  <div style="position: relative;">
                     <div class="CodeMirror-gutter-wrapper" style="left: -53px;" contenteditable="false">
                        <div class="CodeMirror-linenumber CodeMirror-gutter-elt" style="left: 0px; width: 21px;">1</div>
                     </div>
                     <pre class=" CodeMirror-line " role="presentation" style="">
                        <span role="presentation">
                           <span cm-text="">​</span>
                        </span>
                     </pre>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div style="position: absolute; height: 14px; width: 1px; border-bottom: 0px solid transparent; top: 26px;" />
   <div class="CodeMirror-gutters" style="height: 40px;">
      <div class="CodeMirror-gutter CodeMirror-linenumbers" style="width: 53px;" />
   </div>
</div>
```

(it's github's gist code area). I'm trying to imitate human's typing of any text, and, finally, create gist. But this is `span`, and `sendKeys` to this element doesn't work. 
All attempts to set text in span didn't affect `Create gist` button - one of the reason such behavior is callback on this `span`.
I need help to imitate human typing to unlock `Create gist button`

Comment: Did you try recording it?

Comment: @TrippKinetics what do you mean?

Comment: Go into Selenium IDE or a similar browser-based tool and record a script where you type something in the field.

Comment: @TrippKinetics but selenium ide 3.0 doesn't support export to java

Comment: How about Katalon Recorder?

Comment: My pleasure.  I made an answer.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by `set text in span didn't affect Create gist button`? In which element do you want to set text? Are you able to do it manually? What are your _Manual Steps_ to `imitate human typing to unlock Create gist button`?

Comment: @DebanjanB yes, i can do it manually, but even recording actions in Katalon doesn't help me, these actions can't be repeated by IDE.

Comment: @DebanjanB I mean, that this button still has property "disabled"

Comment: @TrippKinetics this is strange, but these actions can't be repeated by Katalon( it can't press the button at last step because of "disabled" property

Comment: @Evgeniy I am afraid as neither I can find any `<button>` tag nor any element with text as **Create gist** within the HTML you have shared. Perhaps through _Selenium_ and _WebDriver_ you can _Automate_ any step which can be performed _Manually_.

Answer (score 1):

If you want Selenium to tell you what command is necessary for a particular action (in this case, typing in a field), you can use Katalon Recorder to record the action in Selenese.  It is then possible to export to Java (or C#, or PHP, or...)